# Creating many instances of a class will fail when there are threads around? - Singleton pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

In the following code, I haven';t used any "threads". Will creating multiple instances still be a problem?   If I use threads, then since threads share the address space - the functioning may get currupted.

Of course there isn't any "need" to create multiple objects, but I do so (the way I have done it here) will that be a problem?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class boiler
    {
        private:
            // Non static variables can't be initialized inside a class.
            bool boilerEmpty;
            bool mixtureBoiled;

        public:
            boiler ()
            {
                boilerEmpty    = true;
                mixtureBoiled = false;
            }
            void fillBoiler() 
            {
                if (boilerEmpty == true)
                {
                    cout << "\nFill boiler.";
                    boilerEmpty = false;
                }
            }

            void boilMixture ()
            {
                if ((boilerEmpty == false) && (mixtureBoiled == false))
                {
                    cout << "\nBoil mixture";
                    mixtureBoiled = true;
                }
            }

            void drainMixture ()
            {
                if ((boilerEmpty == false) && (mixtureBoiled == true))
                {
                    cout << "\nDrain mixture.";
                    boilerEmpty = true;
                }
            }
    };

    int main ()
    {
        boiler b, c;
        b.fillBoiler ();
        b.boilMixture ();
        b.drainMixture ();

        c.fillBoiler ();
        c.boilMixture ();
        c.drainMixture ();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something... But I don't see any static variables...

Comment: @Andrew I haven't put any static variables. Do I need them?

Comment: Threading has nothing to do with multiple objects here as there are no statics. The only issue can be simultaneous access from 2 or more threads to the same object.

Comment: @KillianDS So, you mean to say that unless I have threads I have nothing to worry?

Comment: Multithreading is a problem only if you share global or staitc data(i.e the same object instance) accross different threads.Why is it a problem? Because multiple threads can race to access the same instance of data.Your class has no static data member nor your program has any global data.So there is no race condition.As long as you create a object in a thread and don't pass it around to other threads(ex: two separate pointers pointing to the same object and being accessed in diff threads), You don't need synchronization.

Comment: Singleton is a design pattern. Multithreading is a programming technique. They are often used together. However, from your code/question it isn't clear where the two clash or if you are simply trying things out to learn more. Can you clarify?

Comment: @dirkgently I just wanted to know how will threads demolish this program (if I use them).

Comment: @Als thanks, your comment was clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only use an instance from one thread, then having many instances will cause you no problems.  The only way that you invite inconsistent behaviour is by trying to use one instance in multiple threads.

If you do use one instance in multiple threads, you will want to investigate using a mutex semaphore to ensure that the instance is being used in only one thread at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Concurrent programming (whether actual multi-threading or not) is challenging in the presence of **shared mutable data** between the multiple threads of execution.

By definition, anything that is **immutable** can be shared without synchronization issues:

- classes data: RTTI, virtual tables
- functions code: on Linux for example, the OS guards the pages with a special mode to ensure they are never written to
- `const` data: string literals, magic numbers declared constants, ...

Therefore, the only things you should be worrying about for concurrent programming is how mutable data may end up being shared. This sharing may occur in two ways:

- explicitly: passing a reference to a variable to another thread of execution
- implicitly: the infamous *global variables*, among which *static* class attributes

In your program, there is no global variable, so sharing would be explicit (if you created a second thread of execution).